# Update adVarChar Field in .ACF File using ADODB Throws Error Multiple-step operation generated errors

Tags: .net, powershell, adodb

I'm in the process of debugging an app and found it uses database connection string encrypted in a "Db" field in an .ACF file. While I worked out how to write a decryption/encryption routine, I'm unable to write back my new value.

Example PowerShell code fragment:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\app\adodb.dll
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $decryptCode

$recordSet = New-Object ADODB.RecordsetClass
$recordSet.Open("c:\app\connectionstring.acf",[Type]::Missing,[ADODB.CursorTypeEnum]::adOpenKeySet,[ADODB.LockTypeEnum]::adLockBatchOptimistic)

$dbEncrypted = $recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value
"Current Connection String: $([Decryptor.NativeMethods]::Decrypt($dbEncrypted))"

# update connection string
$newConnectionString = "<blah blah blah>"

$recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = [Decryptor.NativeMethods]::Encrypt($newConnectionString)
$recordSet.Save()
```

This code reads the connection string and decrypts it OK. IT also encrypts the new connection string fine. However when attempting to update the "Db" field it throws error:

> Exception setting "Value": "Multiple-step operation generated errors.
>   Check each status value." At C:\debugging\Decryptor.ps1:329 char:1
>   + $recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = [Decryptor.NativeMethods]::Encrypt($n ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

[Decryptor.NativeMethods]::Encrypt returns a string, although not all characters are printable, and the string is longer than the original string.

I can set the DB value to normal strings, or the string I just read from the database:

```
$recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = $dbEncrypted
```

I thought it may be size, as the original encrypted string was 147 characters, but the new one is 179 characters. So I cut the new string to 147 characters, and even less but it still won't set. So I suspect it is due to content of the string.

The string I am trying to set looks like this:

> £àöÌóÓàù:Ò¡J·DµÕ1R|SÀgÐqíÀZ(Lá2   !¯'B$Rä!kýÈg\ISX   êmh®¾   oÔçþOZißlß%¼ù@
>   ÕeæB¦ëvpâNÉ   oSÆ!fZÆÿ²ÔFôó Ûvºä2øg
>   ¹¼`àU¸ÏAß0g§ÿ¨brÁÆ¾('îÙ2ÿééµHãhû`=¿   6Å=#´ú½¬ö

$recordSet shows the following values:

```
Properties       : {IAccessor, IChapteredRowset, IColumnsInfo, IColumnsRowset...}
AbsolutePosition : 1
ActiveConnection : 
BOF              : False
Bookmark         : 1
CacheSize        : 1
CursorType       : adOpenStatic
EOF              : False
Fields           : {DB}
LockType         : adLockBatchOptimistic
MaxRecords       : 0
RecordCount      : 5
Source           : c:\app\connectionstring.acf
AbsolutePage     : 1
EditMode         : adEditNone
Filter           : 0
PageCount        : 1
PageSize         : 10
Sort             : 
Status           : 8
State            : 1
CursorLocation   : adUseClient
MarshalOptions   : adMarshalAll
DataSource       : ADODB.RecordsetClass
ActiveCommand    : 
StayInSync       : True
DataMember       : 
Index            :
```

The current settings for recordset.Fields["db"] shows:

$recordSet.Fields["Db"]

```
Status          : 0
ActualSize      : 147
Attributes      : 4
DataFormat      : 
DefinedSize     : 255
Name            : DB
NumericScale    : 0
OriginalValue   : 
Precision       : 0
Properties      : {BASECOLUMNNAME, BASETABLENAME, BASECATALOGNAME, BASESCHEMANAME...}
Type            : adVarChar
UnderlyingValue : 
Value           : £àöÌóÓà™ù:Ò¡J·DµÕ1R|SÀgÐqíÀZ(Lá2  !¯'B$Rä\!kýÈ˜g\ISX  ê‰mh®¾  oÔçþOZißlß%¼ù€@Š˜ ÕeæB¦ëvpâNÉ   
                  oSÆ!fZ–Æÿ²ÔFôó Ûvºä2øÀü"ëöÑ@Õ k§«üdÊ'Ó‹Û§1j©
```

$recordSet.Fields["Db"].Properties contains

```
Attributes Name                      Type Value
---------- ----                      ---- -----
         1 BASECOLUMNNAME      adVarWChar      
         1 BASETABLENAME       adVarWChar      
         1 BASECATALOGNAME     adVarWChar      
         1 BASESCHEMANAME      adVarWChar      
         1 KEYCOLUMN            adBoolean False
         1 ISAUTOINCREMENT      adBoolean False
         1 RELATIONCONDITIONS adVarBinary      
         1 CALCULATIONINFO    adVarBinary      
         1 OPTIMIZE             adBoolean False
```

In further testing with different strings found this string works:

```
$recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = "£àöÌóÓà"
```

But this string does not work:

```
$recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = "£àöÌóÓà"

Exception setting "Value": "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."
At line:1 char:1
+ $recordSet.Fields["Db"].Value = "£àöÌóÓà"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Further testing identifies the following:

```
 $broken = "£àöÌóÓà"
$working = "£àöÌóÓà"
# $broken.Length  = 9
# $working.Length = 7 

[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($working)
194
163
195
160
195
182
195
140
195
179
195
147
195
160

[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($broken)
194
163
195
160
195
182
195
140
195
179
195
147
195
160
194
129
194
153
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by a flaw in the encryption routine which created a result that looked visually the same as the correct encryption, but byte representation of the resultant string was different.

The encryption routine had been copied from a decompiled DLL and utilized a function to convert Byte array to string:

```
    private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] Buffer)
            {

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Buffer.Count);
                foreach (byte num in Buffer)
                {
                    builder.Append(Convert.ToString((char)num));
                }
return builder.ToString();
}
```

I replaced the code using .NET in-built conversion approach:

```
 private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] Buffer)
        {
                return Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer.ToArray());
}
```

This latter method generated strings while visually the same, were byte-for-byte different, and were accepted by the ADODB updating commands.